# OneNote API - REST & Postman

Tags: rest, postman, onenote

I am trying to integrate the OneNote API as part of a new application. Is it possible to use Google Chrome's POSTMAN REST Client to test the API? The OneNote API appears to be standard REST, so there should be no reason why not.

To login, I followed the documentation and did a GET request in POSTMAN to

```
https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=myClientIdIsHere&scope=wl.signin&response_type=token&redirect_uri=dontKnowWhatToPutHere
```

Broken down, that is:

```
https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf
client_id=myClientIdIsHere
scope=wl.signin
response_type=token
redirect_uri=dontKnowWhatToPutHere
```

I tried the following based off advice from this blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/onenotedev/archive/2014/07/23/how-to-authenticate-with-microsoft-account-in-a-chrome-extension.aspx

```
https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=myClientIdIsHere&scope=wl.signin&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf
```

When I do a GET request to this, I get HTML back, but it does not show up in the preview mode.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: It looks like POSTMAN sandboxes the returned html page. This prevents javascript from running. Would that explain why nothing appears in the preview mode?

Comment: Figured it out after more experimentation. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34446337/onenote-api-postman-rest

Answer (score 1):

The code that you are trying to execute is just the initial part of the oAuth login process.

As you have mentioned the below peice

> redirect_uri=dontKnowWhatToPutHere

redirect_uri is the URL of your application. Once the authentication is success, the server will redirect the navigation to provided URL and you can proceed further from here. Just keep in mind that the URL given is as same as the one you have provided while creating the azure app. If they do not match, the server is going to simply throw an exception.

Please change the JSON to

```
https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf
client_id=myClientIdIsHere
scope=wl.signin
response_type=token
redirect_uri=http://localhost:8008/login
```

Replace http://localhost:8008/login with your application login route.