# OneNote API & Postman REST

Tags: rest, oauth, onenote-api

I'm attempting to use the [OneNote REST API](http://dev.onenote.com/docs#/reference). In order to test the features, I'm tyring to use [Postman REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en).
[image: Postman OAuth 2.0]

I am using Postman's built in OAuth 2.0 flow with the following parameters:

```
Authorization URL: https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf
Access Token URL: https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf
Client ID: CLIENT_ID
Client Secret: CLIENT_SECRET
Scope (Optional): wl.signin%20wl.basic
```

Below you can see the setup I am using for the MS App Dashboard.

[image]

I am able to get the token, but when I attempt to call a REST API endpoint, the API returns "401 unauthorized".

[image]

Is there something I'm missing here? I think the scope is right, and the space character is properly escaped. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some more research into the scopes and found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn807159.aspx)

Looks like I needed to use `wl.signin%20office.onenote%20office.onenote_create` to get sign in, basic features, and write features.

I'll leave this post up here so anyone else trying to figure this out can save a few hours!

Answer (score 0):

This looks correct, thanks for posting this.  The scopes are important and must be correct so the user knows what they are allowing the app to access.